# Genus 2 - Points at Infinity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading Cassels and Flynn's book on Genus 2 curves

In the background section, they have the following:

> Still working over an algebraically closed field $\bar{k}$, we suppose that the characteristic is not 2 and take as an example the curve $\mathcal{C}$ given in the affine plane by $$ Y^2 = \prod_{j=1}^6 (X-\theta_j).$$ It is not complete: there are two points $\mathfrak{b}_1$, $\mathfrak{b}_2$ 'at infinity'.

I'm trying to see this. So, I homogenize to get
$$Y^2Z^4 = \prod_{j=1}^6 (X-\theta_jZ).$$
A point at infinity is of the form $[a:b:0]$ and substituting implies that $a=0$ and so $[a:b:0]\sim [0:1:0]$. So, I only get one point at infinity. Do the authors mean that $\mathfrak{b}_1 = \mathfrak{b}_2$ occurs with multiplicity 2? In what sense do points at infinity have a multiplicity.

They go on to say

> $X^{-1}$ is a local uniformizer at the $\mathfrak{b}_j$

Again, I'm having difficulty with points at infinity here. This implies that $X$ has a pole of order 1 at $\mathbf{b}_j$. In what sense does $X$ have a pole at $[0:1:0]$ and how do we determine it's multiplicity?

Comment: If you take the projective closure in $\mathbb{P}^2$, you get just one point, but it is singular, as can be checked by computing partial derivatives. If you resolve the singularity by blowing up, you'll get two nonsingular points. Alternatively, people usually consider the equation $Y^2 = \prod_{j=1}^6 (X-\theta_j Z)$ in the weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1,3,1)$, where it is homogeneous of weight $6$. Using this equation, if you look on the line $Z=0$, you should get $2$ points at infinity.

Comment: Why would we consider the curve in weighted projective space as opposed to traditional projective space. Also, I can't seem to compute the multiplicity at infinity correctly. I get a multiplicity of 4 for the point at infinity, when Bezout say's I hould get 6.

Comment: The clear advantage to taking the closure in weighted projective space is that it results in a smooth, projective model of the curve. Taking the closure in $\mathbb{P}^2$ yields a singular curve, which you then have to desingularize if you want to get a smooth complete curve. I've written a longer answer below about the choice of weights.

Comment: Viktor Vaughn's comment in different words. The function $Y/X^3$ distinquishes between the two points at infinity. On one branch $Y/X^3\to+1$, on the other $Y/X^3\to-1$.

Comment: Much the same way that equations like $Y^2=q(X)$, $q(X)$ quartic, gives a genus one curve.

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into an answer:

If you take the projective closure in $\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}} \P^2$, you get just one point at infinity, but it is singular, as can be checked by computing partial derivatives. If you resolve the singularity by blowing up, you'll get two nonsingular points.

Alternatively, people usually consider the closure of $C$ in the weighted projective space $\P(1,3,1)$, where it is given by the weighted homogeneous equation $Y^2 = \prod_{j=1}^6 (X-\theta_jZ)$ of degree $6$. Using this equation, if you look on the line $Z=0$, you will find 2 (smooth) points at infinity.

But why these weights? This can be explained by consider the orders of poles of the functions $x$ and $y$. The TL;DR is that $x$ has pole divisor $\renewcommand{\div}{\operatorname{div}}  \div_\infty(x) = \infty_1 + \infty_2$, while $y$ has pole divisor $\div_\infty(y) = 3(\infty_1 + \infty_2)$. Thus it's natural to take $x$ and $y$ to have weights $1$ and $3$, respectively.

Suppose $C$ is a smooth projective genus $2$ curve, just abstractly without a defining equation. We will find an equation using Riemann-Roch. Let $K$ be a canonical divisor for $C$. Then $\deg(K) = 2g-2 = 2$. Since $h^0(K) = g = 2$, then there is a nonzero rational function $f \in H^0(K)$, so $\div(f) + K \geq 0$. Replacing $K$ by $\div(f) + K$, we may assume that $K$ is effective, so $K$ is the sum of $2$ points. Denoting these points by $\infty_1$ and $\infty_2$, then $K = \infty_1 + \infty_2$. (Generically these $2$ points will be distinct, but it is possible to take $K = 2P$ where $P$ is a Weierstrass point. In that case, the calculation below goes slightly differently.) Write $\newcommand{\iinfty}{\underline{\infty}} \iinfty = \infty_1 + \infty_2$, so $K = \iinfty$.

Let's compute $h^0(m \iinfty)$ for $m = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$. Since $C$ is projective, then there are no nonconstant regular functions, so $h^0(0) = 1$. Since $K = \iinfty$, then
$$
h^0(\iinfty) = h^0(K) = g = 2 \, ,
$$
so there is some nonconstant function $x \in H^0(\iinfty)$. For divisors $D$ with $\deg(D) > 2g-2 = 2$, we have
$$
h^0(D) = 1 - g + \deg(D) = \deg(D) - 1
$$
by Riemann-Roch. Thus for all $m \geq 2$, we have $h^0(m \iinfty) = 2m - 1$. Then $h^0(2 \iinfty) = 3$, but $1, x, x^2$ all belong to $H^0(2 \iinfty)$, so we don't find any new functions. For $m = 3$, however, we have $h^0(3 \iinfty) = 5$. Now $1, x, x^2, x^3$ are all in $H^0(3 \iinfty)$, but that means there's still one more linearly independent function: call this function $y$. Thus $\div_\infty(x) = \iinfty$ and $\div_\infty(y) = 3 \iinfty$, which explains the choice of grading.

If we continue on to $m = 6$, then we find that $h^0(6 \iinfty) = 11$ and
$$
1, x, x^2, x^3, y, x^4, xy, x^5, x^2 y, x^6, x^3 y
$$
form a basis for $H^0(6 \iinfty)$. But $y^2$ also belongs to $H^0(6 \iinfty)$, so there is a linear dependence among these monomials. With a little more work, this yields a Weierstrass equation
$$
y^2 + h(x) y = f(x)
$$
where $\deg(h) \leq 3$ and $\deg(f) \leq 6$.

Here's a table summarizing these calculations:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|l}
m & h^0(m \iinfty) & \text{basis for $H^0(m \iinfty)$}\\
\hline \hline
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1, x\\
2 & 3 & 1, x, x^2\\
3 & 5 & 1, x, x^2, x^3, y\\
4 & 7 & 1, x, x^2, x^3, y, x^4, xy\\
5 & 9 & 1, x, x^2, x^3, y, x^4, xy, x^5, x^2 y\\
6 & 11 & 1, x, x^2, x^3, y, x^4, xy, x^5, x^2 y, x^6, x^3 y
\end{array}
$$

We also see that $1/x$ is a uniformizer at $\infty_1$ and $\infty_2$: $x$ has a simple pole at each of these points, so $1/x$ has a simple zero there.

For more on hyperelliptic curves, see [these notes](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Esgal018/crypto-book/ch10.pdf) by Steven Galbraith.

Comment: I guess the natural question is given an abstract curve of genus 2, how does one get the singular model as described by the book?

Answer (score 0):

The Riemann surface of the analytic function $Y=\sqrt{\prod_{j=1}^6 (X-\theta_j)}$ indeed has two points over infinity. It can be seen from the fact that the square root of a sixth degree polynomial doesn't change its sign when passing around origin along a circle of a big enough radius. The function $X^{-1}$ is an uniformizer for the Riemann sphere at infinity, and since the covering over infinity is unramified, the pullback of $X^{-1}$ is also an uniformizer for the points over infinity.

About the question in comments, if we put $Y=1$ and $X=0$, the equation of projective closure becomes $(\prod_{j=1}^6\theta_j)Z^6-Z^4=0$. This equation has a root $Z=0$ of multiplicity 4, and, in general, 2 other roots, so there are no contradiction with Bezout's Theorem.

Comment: I don't follow most of these claims: I don't see how the square roots of a sixth degree polynomial doesn't change it's sign. If we're passing around the origin in a circle, doesn't this mean we are dealing with complex number and therefore we have a branch? Thus we'd change sign going over the branch. If there is a second point at infinity, what are it's coordinates?

Why is the covering over infinity unramified?

Also, I'm concerned with the multiplicity with $\mathcal{C}$ and the line at infinity given by $Z=0$. $(0:1:0)$ occurs with multiplicity 4, so where are the remaining 2?

Comment: If we're passing around the origin in a circle containing all roots $\theta_j$, then we stay at the same branch. We can consider a Riemann surface without global coordinates, as a completion of an affine complex curve in the usual topology. A ramified covering with two sheets is unramified at the points with two preimages. Putting $Z=0$ we get $X^6=0$, so your point has miltiplicity 6 along this line.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get why is the covering unramified at infinity. I get why the cover is ramified at the points $(\theta_j:1:0)$. I still don't understand why the authors would claim there are two points at infinity for this curve.